# My DNS is down but can I find records somehow from the DNS from some cache?

Tags: domain-name-system

My DNS server is down but I need to find some record which existed there on that DNS server. The DNS server just went down one hour ago. Is there any cache of DNS records that I can lookup? My domain is samaritans.org.hk

Comment: Bringing the server back up would be a good start. I can see from the whois records that it is under your control.

Comment: If you are lucky and can track down someone who might have used whatever record you're looking for before its TTL expires, then you might get even more lucky and they can pull it out of their cache. Otherwise... nope

Comment: how do you pull it out of someones cache? .. ie OSX?

Comment: I think you use "dig" to query another DNS server.  I don't think you need to do anything special to pull it out of the cache, but if the TTL hasn't expired another DNS server may still serve up the old records if you're quick:  dig @some.other.nameserver.org your.domain.com  (http://www.madboa.com/geek/dig/)

Comment: Problem with the above method is that you have to select entry by entry....a tedious process and you have to know all the records that you lost.

Comment: Why don't you just restore from your backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from your note that your PRIMARY DNS server is down.  Hopefully you configured some secondary or backup; DNS servers.  If so, if you can get to one of these secondary DNS servers (before the zone expires), they will have a full copy of the last forward zone file stored textually that could be easily used in reconstructing these records on the Primary.